# WPF Adding text from textbox to column in ListBox with multi-columns

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I created a listbox with four columns

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,33" Name="listBox1" Width="464" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBoxItem Content="Produkt" Width="210"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Ilość" Width="50"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Cena (za sztukę)" Width="100"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Koszt całkowity" Width="100"/>
        </ListBox>
```

Now I want to have a textbox and button that add text from textbox under second column (its called "Ilość" in my code). How am I supposed to do that?

I tried this

```
listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
```

But this actually just create another column

Listbox is inside Grid.

Comment: Are you confusing rows with columns?

Comment: Um, no. At least I hope so :D

Comment: http://scr.hu/76jw/75e3p
This is how it looks now. I want to add text where I drew these lines.

Comment: Ok I should notice that, listbox is inside Grid, I forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

Most WPF developers end up using MVVM as it creates a clean, maintainable and testable code. Microsoft uses MVVM internally when it creates some of its newer products. For example, Microsoft Blend is written entirely using MVVM.

In this case, you would bind the listbox  to an `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel, and have a custom `DataTemplate` to display the results.

Or, you could use a grid to display the items, which would create a table.

There are many examples of this on the web.